# how can we pass multiple arguments in the background functions in karate feature file

Tags: karate

i am passing the two arguments to my custom function but in background while i am passing the arguments it's skipping first taking second one only arugment.
here is the sample code

```
* def LoadToTigerGraph =
    """
    function(args1,args2) {
      var CustomFunctions = Java.type('com.optum.graphplatform.util.CareGiverTest');
      var cf = new CustomFunctions();
      return cf.testSuiteTrigger(args1,args2);
    }"""

    #*eval if (karate.testType == "component") karate.call(LoadToTigerGraph '/EndTestSample.json')

        * def result = call LoadToTigerGraph "functional","/EndTestSample.json"
```

output :

```
test type is ************/EndTestSample.json
path is *************undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pass two arguments, you need to send them as two json key/value.

```
* def result = call LoadToTigerGraph { var1: "functionnal", var2: "/EndTestSample.json" }
```

And you just have to use `args.var1` and `args.var2` in your function `function(args)`

Comment: actually for JS you can do this: `* def result = LoadToTigerGraph("functional", "/EndTestSample.json")`

Comment: have you a sample with args are variables please?